# How can I get data from a Table

Tags: excel, excel-2013, validation

Can someone assist me on how can I get data from a table in Excel 2013?

I have a table named Personal:

[image: Personal]

and I want to have a control in a cell like this:
(I do not know how to add this control in a cell)

[image: Personal_Button]

So I can select data from the table:

[image]

I googled a lot before asking here, and couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your google foo could do with some polish. For the dropdown try DATA > Data Tools, Data Validation,

Allow: List
Source: whatever the range is for the data in your table.